# How to color text from file_get_contents in php cli

Tags: php

I want to get text from a file with file_get_contents and color it on php cli.

File-From-Server: http://localhost/file

Hello This Is A new Text

PHP Cli Code:

```
<?php $var=file_get_contents(http://localhost/file); echo $var; ?>
```

I want to modify http://localhost/file and color the codes on PHP Cli.

i tried modify http://localhost/file to

\033[33mHello This Is A new Text\033[0m

But it's not working it printing the full text.

Comment: _"But it's not working it printing the full text."_ - that's because it only gets treated as text. The escape sequences you used in there only actually work, if this text gets interpreted by the PHP parser. This is pretty much the same, as if you had `foo\nbar` as the content of your text file - if you output that as you did above, you will only get the _text_ `\n` shown in that place. It would be different, if you had `echo "foo\nbar";` instead.

Comment: Try and replace the `\033` with the result of `chr(27)` (octal 033 is 27 in dec.)

Comment: Can you please prepare a sample code for me? It will be appreciated.

Comment: `$var = str_replace('\033', chr(27), $var);` Or, `$var = str_replace('\033', "\033", $var);` should probably do the same thing. (This gets interpreted as code, an inside double quotes the escape sequence is valid.)